# Что выполняется быстрее

Tags: c#

Есть класс `Test` и свойство `T` в нем, например

```
class Test
{
    private static int[] t;
    public static int[] T
    {
        get { return t; }
    }
}
```

Будет многократное использование данного свойства. Какая из функций будет работать быстрее из приведенного ниже примера?

```
void Func()
{
    Array.IndexOf(Test.T, 0);
    //Многократное использование, сравнение
}

void Func1()
{
    int[] temp = Test.T;
    Array.IndexOf(temp, 0);
    //Многократное использование, сравнение
}
```

Я предполагаю что `Func1` будет быстрее, но прошу подтвердить или опровергнуть мои мысли.

Comment: ответ - одинаково, компилятор сам приведет все к нужному ему типу, т.е. если второй вариант окажеться быстрее, компилятор из первого себе сделает второй (но при условии что не будет изменяться исходный массив)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый код будет немного быстрее т.к. в нем нету 1го лишнего действия.
Но вообще там прирост будет на столько низким что ты этого никак не заметишь, даже, в правильно проведенных тестах на быстродействие.

Дело в том что масив - это ссылочный тип. И не важно как ты к нему обращаешся - по прямой ссылке из некоего обьекта(`Test.T`) или по скопированной ссылке из свойств некоего обьекта ( `int[] temp` ).

```
int[] temp = Test.T; 
//здесь копируется ссылка на массив, а не сам массив!
// А а значит все последующие обращения будут занимать одинаковое время
// независимо от того к чему ты будешь обращатся -- хоть к Test.T хоть к temp
```

Так что т.к. разницы, фактически, никакой -- используй тот код, который будет более читабельным по твоему мнению.

И наперед скажу, что если ты попробуешь скопировать массив вместо копирования ссылки на него - это только приведет к уменьшению скорости работы твоей программы.

Оптимизируй тогда, когда ты видишь в этом практический смысл. Не пытайся делать оптимизацию ради оптимизации всюду.

Comment: А мне кажется, что во втором случае лишняя переменная просто будет выпелена, так как ее результаты нигде не используются.

Comment: на этапе компиляции? Возможно и так.

Answer (score 0):

Подойду к вопросу в общем.

Что значит "быстрее"? Какую именно стадию измеряем?

Второй вариант кода длиннее. Значит, набирать его на клавиатуре дольше.
Более длинный исходный код будет дольше записываться на диск и считываться с него.
Более длинный код будет дольше компилироваться.
Получившийся исполнимый файл тоже будет больше. Соответственно, он в итоге будет дольше загружаться.
Байт-код второго вариант будет длиннее. Следовательно, перед непосредственным выполнением он будет дольше JIT-компилироваться.

Как вам это?
Конечно, вы имели в виду другое, когда говорили "быстрее". Но вы *не уточнили* все детали. Вы плохой заказчик: плохо сформулировали ТЗ. В итоге результат - ...
Итого, для начала учитесь правильно формулировать, что именно вам надо.